# Maximal dimension of representations needed to determine a group

Tags: gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory

If a finite group $G$ is abelian, it is essentially determined by its 1-dimensional complex representations (Pontryagin duality).

For an arbitrary finite group we can ask what the least number $n$ is such that its complex representations of dimension $\leq$ $n$ determine it. Let's provisionally call $n$ the representation dimension $d_\rho(G)$ of $G$.

Is there a formula for $d_\rho(G)$? Is it related to the length of derived or central series of $G$, or expressible in terms of cohomology of $G$?

Comment: An abelian group is only determined by its $1$-dimensional complex representations in the category of abelian groups. In general there is no such number $d_\rho(G)$ without further assumptions on $G$.

Comment: Would you provide a precise definition of *"$G$ is determined by its $\le n$-dimensional representations"*?

Comment: To recover G I guess you need to know how to decompose the tensor product of simples into simples and use Tannaka duality.  So I guess in some sense you need to know reps up to the square of the largest degree irreducible.  But you do need a precise definition. Maybe look at https://mathoverflow.net/questions/155743/can-one-explain-tannaka-krein-duality-for-a-finite-group-to-a-computer-ho